# Close the next window in Vim

Tags: vim

Since I have a vertical split, how can I close the *left window* while the cursor is on the *right window*?
I know I can go to the next window with `Ctrl-w w` and then close it but there might be a faster way.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:-q` or `:-q!` should do the job.

According to `:h CTRL-W_q`:

```
:q[uit]
:{count}q[uit]
...
                If [count] is greater than the last window number the last
                window will be closed:
                    :1quit  " quit the first window
                    :$quit  " quit the last window
                    :9quit  " quit the last window
                            " if there are less than 9 windows opened
                    :-quit  " quit the previews window
                    :+quit  " quit the next window
                    :+2quit " quit the second next window
```

I presume `previews window` above should read `previous window`...

Answer (score 3):

If you have only two windows open, the key combination [`Ctrl-w o`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#CTRL-W_o) (or the command [`:only`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:only)) will close the next (and only other) window.

In general, `Ctrl-w o` closes all windows except the current window.

Comment: Thank you, after the first answer I typed `:h CTRL-W` and I found that trick too.